# Embed Outlook Calendar in OneNote 2013

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

Is there a way to embed an Outlook 2013 (or Windows 8 Calendar App) calendar onto OneNote 2013 in a similar fashion to how an Excel sheet is embedded?

Answer (score 0):

are you familiar with ONETASTIC?

there may be something you can use, or manipulate to your needs.

http://omeratay.com/onetastic/

Comment: Hi xman. While this may theoretically answer the question, we encourage answers that go into some detail on how the proposed solution will help with the stated problem. Could you perhaps **[edit]** this answer to expand on it and describe how Onetastic may be useful?